# Error: Property "todoListId" cannot be changed (using todo-list example)

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback, v4l2loopback

I have clone the example "todo-list" from github and without modifying anything the @post todo-lists is created without. then I use the responsed "Id" to @post /todo-lists/{id}/todos and it gave error

> Unhandled error in POST /todo-lists/3/todos: 500 Error: Property "todoListId" cannot be changed!
>   at Object.constrainDataObject (D:\Projects\NodeJs\lbex\loopback4-example-todo-list\node_modules@loopback\repository\dist\repositor
>   ies\constraint-utils.js:49:19)
>   at DefaultHasManyRepository.create (D:\Projects\NodeJs\lbex\loopback4-example-todo-list\node_modules@loopback\repository\dist\rela
>   tions\has-many\has-many.repository.js:21:59)
>   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

I also tried to create everything by myself following the example.
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/HasMany-relation.html
It sill give the same error.

PS. I have posted this on the loopback github but I don't know if that's the right place to post. So, I posted it here instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be sending todoListId in the request body. Remove that. Loopback juggler automatically attaches that value upon saving.
Below request body worked for me.

```
{
  "title": "Testing 123",
  "desc": "This is a testing description",
  "isComplete": true
}
```